# Python Jira Rest Api code generates invalid string

Tags: python, jira-rest-api, jsondecoder

I am trying to connect to Jira Rest Api using Python and trying to save data into text file but i am getting huge string returned as response which seems to be invalid string and it also contains html tags.

I am trying to connect Jira using Api token, projectkey and url. Do i need to provide User, Passoword authentication also ?

Below is my code:

```
import base64
import os
from jira import JIRA
import sys
import requests
import json
import shutil

os.environ["HTTPS_PROXY"] = "XXXX"

# Base encode email and api token
cred =  "Basic " + base64.b64encode(b'XXX@bk.de:XXXX').decode("utf-8")
# Set header parameters
headers = {
   "Accept": "application/json",
   "Content-Type": "application/json",
   "Authorization" : cred
}

# Enter your project key here
projectKey = "TEST"

# Update your site url
url = "https://jira-test.net/secure/RapidBoard.jspa?rapidView=194&projectKey=" + projectKey

# Send request and get response
response = requests.request(
   "GET",
   url,
   headers=headers
)

# Decode Json string to Python
json_data = json.loads(response.text)

# Display issues
for item in json_data["issues"]:
    print(item["id"] + "\t" + item["key"] + "\t" +
        item["fields"]["issuetype"]["name"] + "\t" +
        item["fields"]["created"]+ "\t" +
        item["fields"]["creator"]["displayName"] + "\t" +
        item["fields"]["status"]["name"] + "\t" +
        item["fields"]["summary"] + "\t"
        )
```

Comment: Add `print(response.text)` right before the `json.loads`, to see if your JSON response is valid

Comment: i have added and i am getting huge string which looks like an error but also it data with html tags ...i dont understand anything

Comment: i think i will edit my question the issue is with code...

Comment: The first thing you need to check is `response.status_code`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your comment the Jira API is returning some HTML code, meaning you probably have an error in your response.

You need to check if you get a 200 response from the API.

Replace

```py
# Decode Json string to Python
json_data = json.loads(response.text)
```

by

```py
# Check for API errors
response.raise_for_status()

# Decode Json string to Python
json_data = response.json()
```

Comment: again it generates same huge invalid response but at the end of the line i can see : requests.exceptions.HTTPError: 401 Client Error: Unauthorized for url:

Comment: You can remove the `print(response.text)` now.

The 401 error means that your URL is incorrect, try to add `print(url)` and to access it manually in your browser.

Comment: yes the url link is correct i try to open in browser...one question the url points to Kanban Board in Jira is this correct ? looks like authentication issue...i am trying to connect Jira using Api token

Comment: I don't know anything about the Jira API, try to look up their doc.